# Most efficient way to make tall pile of objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, rigid-bodies

Ok Im trying to make a TALL pile of objects, ideally where the outer layer/ones touchable by the user on ground level have rigid bodies and are able to be moved.

Ive succeeded using https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjem72Awa3eAhWKEZAKHbHMCBcQwqsBMAB6BAgGEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DPJBPCnuaqIo&usg=AOvVaw1ewMypDbMyIV-qz8LZoo2e to make a shallow pile of objects that can move around, but no matter how many objects I drop in play mode, they inevitably bounce off each other and distribute out on the ground.

I need a TALL pile that won't all collapse - reducing polys as much as possible for gameplay, whats the best way to do this? Is there a way to use a particle system like I did with blender and a premade object:

[image]

How is this typically done in unity?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to stack them in your scene, enter play mode, let them fall and come to rest then just keep going back and forth. Once you have a good stack. Clear all the random debri, then create an empty and drag all the items into it in the inspector scene view, then you can make the empty into a prefab and set pikes wherever you want.

Alternatively you can remove there rigid bodies and parent them to an empty and just add a simple block collider(if you don't want the column to come apart)